# Want to use MongoDB in servlets

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, servlets

I currently have knowledge of JSP and Servlets and want to use MongoDB, but I can find only ways to use Mongo with maven. Just want to ask if i can use Mongo without maven?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Maven is a build and dependency management tool. MongoDB is a Database. They are completly unrelated. With Maven it is just simpler to gather MongoDB java driver dependency. You just need to declare it in your maven pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Without maven, you need to manually download the required jar file and manually add it to your classpath. Use this location to get the required jar file:

> https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/

Then you can just continue according to any MongoDB tutorial, such as:

> http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-hello-world-example/